# How would i render 2D floor plans on iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

HI,

I want to create simple floor plans like this and render it on iphone not as image.

[image]

My problem is how should i create this floor plans so that i can render it on phone?? Should I use OpenGL?? or Quartz??. If I use any of them can I create a Tool which will help people to create simple floor plans by drag drop and then view it on there Iphone??

Comment: If you want to be able to zoom in and out, and add text to it to indicate rooms and sizes, I believe a vector-based solution (i.e. drawing lines, shapes etc) is a good call.

Comment: what i want it to create something similar but very basic thing like small version of blender which will be used to create this kind of plans which i can view on iphone

Comment: no i dont want to draw it on iphone i want to render it on my iphone i want to draw it on some where else

Comment: can i u point any example the link which you gives has lot but was looking some more

Comment: hi joe thanks will give it a try

Comment: I am also interested to know this, I have a requirement where data comes from back-end with which I need to draw a floor plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything you need to know:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

You absolutely do not need to bother with OpenGL or anything like that for something so simple.  This is what the Mac/iPhone were made to do, so have fun.

If you're just tinkering around and don't want to dedicate a year to learning general XCode programming, perhaps get Corona and do it in a fraction of the time.